# Google Search Console Rejects a Valid Sitemap with no Explanation

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console -> Sitemaps -> "Add a new sitemap"

Enter a perfectly valid sitemap URL (mine is https://helios-public-assets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sitemap.xml), and Google responds with:

[image]

No error, no indication of what is wrong, the sitemap looks valid and fine to me (it loads OK), just less-than-helpful Google interface.

Any ideas what is wrong here or is this a GSC bug?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: yes good call   .....

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because for another exchange

Comment: MOVING TO: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137706/google-search-console-rejects-a-valid-sitemap-with-no-explanation